# Unexpected element <activity> found in <manifest> while using Google Admob

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to implement Google Admob in a Xamarin.Forms application, but after adding the activity in the Xamarin.Forms base class library and implementing it in the android portion of the app I got the following error in the AndroidManifest.xml file `an unexpected element <activity> found in <manifest>.` I tried to move it inside the `<application>` element, but when running the program again it gets automatically moved outside of that element. At this point I don't know what to do. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Edit: As per Bokens request I've created a gist: https://gist.github.com/leodk2/f7570d0c61867e3d177706a27a7ed317

Edit: I should mention that the manifest file is an auto-generated file.

Comment: Post here whole Manifest file.

Comment: The manifest is a bit too long so I've created a gist: https://gist.github.com/leodk2/f7570d0c61867e3d177706a27a7ed317

Answer (score 2):

As discussed [here](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/4114), the activity needs to appear inside the application element.

Answer (score 0):

In your Manifest file,you have two activities

```
<activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
```

in your `<application>`,try to delete the one outside `<application>`

**Update** (if you use Xamarin.Android 10.0):

Try to switch back from `AAPT2` to `AAPT` for a particular project, check and then re-uncheck the **Use incremental packaging system (aapt2)** setting in the Visual Studio project property pages, or set the `$(AndroidUseAapt2)` MSBuild property to `false` by hand in your `.csproj` file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <AndroidUseAapt2>false</AndroidUseAapt2>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: I tried deleting the element, but when I run the program it just gets generated again.For completeness sake I also tried deleting both of them, but that didn't help either.

Comment: @LeoRønsholtMikkelsen What's your device version ? Android 10.0 ?Check above update

Comment: I am using Android 8.1 on the Visual Studio built-in emulator and the project is targeting Android 10. Also, when I switched from AAPT2 to AAPT I got some other errors, but not additional activity.

Comment: @LeoRønsholtMikkelsen what errors ? Will `an unexpected element <activity> found in <manifest>` be throwed in the error ?